# Criar rota para método webapi com parâmetros via querystring

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Tenho a seguinte rota na classe `WebApiConfig` de um projeto **AspNet WepApi**

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
        );
```

**Editado: Utilizando a resposta do @GabrielColetta**: A Rota ficou da forma como está abaixo, e agora funciona a url `http://localhost:62027/Pedidos/Todos?pagina=1&filtro=117` porém não funciona a seguinte url `http://localhost:62027/Pedidos/Todos?filtro=117`, só funciona somente quando é passado ambos os parametros na querystring.

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

O que funciona adequadamente para as URL e métodos abaixo:

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(Pedido))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Detalhes(int id)

http://localhost:62027/Pedidos/Detalhes/104
```

Porém para a URL e metodo abaixo não funciona

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(IPagedList<Pedido>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Todos(string filtro, string pagina)

http://localhost:62027/Pedidos/Todos?filtro=s&pagina=1
http://localhost:62027/Pedidos/Todos
```

Sendo exibido a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um outro projeto **AspNet MVC** que possui a mesma rota e funciona adequadamente, qual o motivo do WebAPI não funcionar? qual a forma correta?

- Projeto WebAPI possui somente uma rota e um único arquivo de rotas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ele não esta encontrando porque o {id} da sua rota não é opcional, então toda rota sua tem que possuir um valor para o {id} ou ele não vai encontrar rota.

Configure sua rota assim e vai funcionar:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Para a url sem o valor de página funcionar você tem que colocar um valor default para página:

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(IPagedList<Pedido>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Todos(string filtro, string pagina = "")
```

Ou você vai ter que fazer uma sobrecarga do método Todos com somente um parâmetro.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta o resultado a sua resposta

Comment: @Ricardo respondido sua edição.

Comment: Porque a rota funciona sem parâmetros padrao no projeto MVC mas não no WEBAPI?

Comment: Funciona? Acredito que você esta usando uma versão mais antiga do framework ou fez alguma configuração que não lembre que diga que é opcional. Caso realmente possa, MVC padrão e a WebApi são dois assembly totalmente diferente e vai ocorrer casos onde ocorre algumas divergências, por mais que a sintaxe seja parecida.

Comment: Só complementando, mas sempre eu uso todos os parametros opcionais, a não ser nos casos onde explicitamente um deles eu tenha que ter. Além disso, no MVC funciona pois o sistema de Binding do MVC é diferente do WEBAPI. No MVC ele faz tudo automaticamente, e quando não tem valor, o binding coloca um valor default. No API é diferente, pois o binding entende que todos os parametros são obrigatórios.

Comment: edtei para `Todos(string filtro = "", string pagina = "")` e funcionou

Comment: Sim, quando você colocar valores default igual eu comentei, ele vai entender que você não precisa passar aquele parametro na url.

Comment: @Ricardo se possível, marca como resposta o post do Gabriel.

Answer (score 0):

Você está passando o parâmetro errado na hora de chamar a action. Na mensagem de erro está `page=1` e a action está esperando a variável com o nome `pagina`.

Comment: Foi um erro de copiar e colar aqui, não deixo nomes em inglês aqui no site.